# Using CUDALink on Ubuntu 18.04

Tags: cudalink, cuda

I can not get CUDALink to work and dont know where to start. None of the CUDA functions works but there are no obvious errors. I am running Ubuntu 18.04 LTS and Mathematica 12.1.

```
Needs["CUDALink`"]
(*works with no errors*)
```

CUDADot (and all other CUDA function throws an error)

```
randM = RandomReal[1, {4000, 4000}];
AbsoluteTiming[CUDADot[randM, randM];]
->CUDADot: CUDALink is not initialized.
```

System Information below:

```
CUDAQ[]
->True
```

```
CUDAInformation[]
->{1 -> {"Name" -> "GeForce GTX 1080 Ti", "Clock Rate" -> 1582000, 
   "Compute Capabilities" -> 6.1, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
   "Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {1024, 1024, 64}, 
   "Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {2147483647, 65535, 65535}, 
   "Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 1024, 
   "Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 49152, 
   "Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, 
   "Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
   "Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 65536, "Texture Alignment" -> 512,
    "Multiprocessor Count" -> 28, "Core Count" -> 3584, 
   "Execution Timeout" -> 0, "Integrated" -> False, 
   "Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
   "Texture1D Width" -> 131072, "Texture2D Width" -> 131072, 
   "Texture2D Height" -> 65536, "Texture3D Width" -> 16384, 
   "Texture3D Height" -> 16384, "Texture3D Depth" -> 16384, 
   "Texture2D Array Width" -> 32768, 
   "Texture2D Array Height" -> 32768, 
   "Texture2D Array Slices" -> 2048, "Surface Alignment" -> 512, 
   "Concurrent Kernels" -> True, "ECC Enabled" -> False, 
   "TCC Enabled" -> False, "Total Memory" -> 11721506816}, 
 2 -> {"Name" -> "GeForce GTX 1070", "Clock Rate" -> 1797000, 
   "Compute Capabilities" -> 6.1, "GPU Overlap" -> 1, 
   "Maximum Block Dimensions" -> {1024, 1024, 64}, 
   "Maximum Grid Dimensions" -> {2147483647, 65535, 65535}, 
   "Maximum Threads Per Block" -> 1024, 
   "Maximum Shared Memory Per Block" -> 49152, 
   "Total Constant Memory" -> 65536, "Warp Size" -> 32, 
   "Maximum Pitch" -> 2147483647, 
   "Maximum Registers Per Block" -> 65536, "Texture Alignment" -> 512,
    "Multiprocessor Count" -> 15, "Core Count" -> 1920, 
   "Execution Timeout" -> 1, "Integrated" -> False, 
   "Can Map Host Memory" -> True, "Compute Mode" -> "Default", 
   "Texture1D Width" -> 131072, "Texture2D Width" -> 131072, 
   "Texture2D Height" -> 65536, "Texture3D Width" -> 16384, 
   "Texture3D Height" -> 16384, "Texture3D Depth" -> 16384, 
   "Texture2D Array Width" -> 32768, 
   "Texture2D Array Height" -> 32768, 
   "Texture2D Array Slices" -> 2048, "Surface Alignment" -> 512, 
   "Concurrent Kernels" -> True, "ECC Enabled" -> False, 
   "TCC Enabled" -> False, "Total Memory" -> 8512602112}}
```

```
CUDAResourcesInformation[]

->{{"Name" -> "CUDAResources", "Version" -> "12.1.0", 
  "WolframVersion" -> "12.1", "Qualifier" -> "Lin64", 
  "SystemID" -> {"Linux-x86-64"}, 
  "Description" -> "{ToolkitVersion -> v10.2, MinimumDriver -> 290}", 
  "Category" -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
  "Keywords" -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
  "UUID" -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
  "Creator" -> Missing["NotAvailable"], 
  "URL" -> Missing["NotAvailable"], "Internal" -> False, 
  "Context" -> {}, "Loading" -> Manual, "AutoUpdating" -> False, 
  "Enabled" -> True, 
  "Location" -> 
   "/home/fatmax/.Mathematica/Paclets/Repository/CUDAResources-Lin64-\
12.1.0", "Hash" -> "3357678c60aa79e333fe04fbb5d04dd7"}}

CUDADriverVersion[]

->"430.50.0"
```

Comment: I think CUDA Toolkit 10.2 requires a minimum driver version of >= 440.33 on Linux.

Comment: The second answer in this thread worked for me: https://askubuntu.com/questions/1028830/how-do-i-install-cuda-on-ubuntu-18-04